# Using Operations to manage imbalances between function calls

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I am writing a `VideoPlayer()` class that has a `start()` and `stop()` function to initiate playback for a given video. Each instance of `VideoPlayer()` manages a single video

The `start()` and `stop()` functions are asynchronous and I get notified via a delegate of success/failure. This delegation is done by a third party SDK.

```
class VideoPlayer {
    func start() {
     // Async call
    }

    func stop() {
     // Async call
    }

    // Callback from third party library with status
    func videoDidStart(view: UIView) {
       // Notify clients
     }
      
     func videoDidStop(stopped: Bool) {
       // Notify clients
     }

}
```

I have clients calling the `start()` and `stop()` function but sometimes it so happens that they are calling start/stop in quick successions. This leads to unexpected behavior.
For example, if the clients call `start()` before a previous call to `stop()` has finished, the video won't play.

Ideally, the clients would wait till I send success/failure notification that I receive via the delegates.

But of course, that's not happening and I am tasked with making the `VideoPlayer()` class manage the imbalance's between `start()` and `stop()` and queue all the calls so everything executes in order.

I would like the `VideoPlayer()` class to ensure that every time there is an imbalance between `start()` and `stop()`, every `start()` is matched with a `stop()` and the rogue calls are put in a queue and execute them after the imbalance has been sorted out.

How do I manage such a thing? I believe I need to use `Operations` with a dependency between `start()` and `stop()`. Should I make `start()/stop()` a single operation and queue the rogue calls until the operation finishes.

Are there other approaches I could use? I have looked `dispatch_groups` and `dispatch_barriers` but I am not sure if they fit my use case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There's a flaw in the architecture: How can you match a `stop` call with a `start` call without some sort of identifier? If you get `start` then `start` then `stop`, plain and simple, exactly how do you think you're going to know which `start` that `stop` belongs to?

Comment: Going by your example, the thought was every time there is a call to `start`, any subsequent calls to `start` are put on hold in a queue and only executed after a call to `stop` is made and completed.

Comment: But if object A says `start` and object B says `start` and then `stop`, you are going to stop A's started process even though it was B who asked to stop. That makes no sense. You need to return an identifier through the `start` callback, and you must require that identifier in the `stop` call; otherwise you have no way to pair them correctly. Once you _do_ have a way to pair them correctly, the answer becomes a lot more evident.

Comment: I see, what would be the approach to take after having a way to pair correctly? Would it be to use `Operations` to add dependencies between the two functions.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need that. I would just keep a queue of all pending `start` calls along with the corresponding identifier, and manage it from there. It sounds like your rule is "don't even allow a start call to start unless all prior start calls in the queue have been stopped (and removed from the list)". — Actually now that I think of it, maybe you can do without the identifier if you have a rule that says you don't even call back from `start` until you really _do_ start, so maybe I overthought that one. But still it seems risky not to pair them up...?

Comment: That makes sense, I can keep a queue of pending `start` calls. I'll look into having an identifier as well. I appreciate your input, thank you.

Comment: OperationQueue could do this pretty easily (with custom, asynchronous, `Operation` subclass). And, yes, I would suggest making the operation start the playing of the video and only finish the operation when the `videoDidStop` delegate is called. But you could also write your own FIFO queue.

Comment: FWIW, the `AVPlayer` has a queue, though, so you don't need to get into writing your own queue. What third party video playing library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why an operation is needed. As a crude example of the sort of thing you are describing, I made a small dispatcher architecture:

```
struct Start {
    let callback : () -> ()
    var started = false
}
class Dispatcher {
    var q = [Start]()
    func start(_ f: @escaping () -> ()) {
        q.append(Start(callback:f))
        self.startFirstOne()
    }
    func stop(_ f: @escaping () -> ()) {
        // assume this can only refer to the first one in the queue
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            self.q.removeFirst()
            f()
            self.startFirstOne()
        }
    }
    private func startFirstOne() {
        guard !q.isEmpty else { return }
        guard !q[0].started else { return }
        print("starting")
        self.q[0].started = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            self.q.first!.callback()
        }
    }
}
```

The `start` calls are queued up, and we don't actually start one until we have received sufficient `stop` calls to bring it to the front of the queue.

I personally don't like this at all, because we are making three very strong assumptions about contract-keeping:

- we assume that everyone who calls `start` will also call `stop`,
- and we are assuming that someone who calls `start` will not call `stop` until after being called back from the `start` call,
- and we are assuming that no one who did not call `start` will ever call `stop`.

Nevertheless, if everyone *does* keep to the contract, then everyone's `stop` will be called back corresponding to that person's `start`. Here's a rough test bed, using random delays throughout to simulate asynchronicity:

```
let d = Dispatcher()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
    d.start {
        print("hearts start")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            d.stop { print("hearts stop") }
        }
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
    d.start {
        print("diamonds start")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            d.stop { print("diamonds stop") }
        }
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
    d.start {
        print("clubs start")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            d.stop { print("clubs stop") }
        }
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
    d.start {
        print("spades start")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int.random(in: 1...10))) {
            d.stop { print("spades stop") }
        }
    }
}
```

Try it, and you'll see that, whatever order and with whatever timing these things run, the start-stop pairs are all maintained by the dispatcher.

As I say, I don't like it. I would prefer to assume that callers might *not* adhere to the contract and be prepared to do something about it. But there it is, for what it's worth.